# App crash after screen change

Tags: java, android

I'll keep this sweet and to the point. I'm just starting to learn to develop applications in Android Studio, and I've come up with this code:

```
package com.example.peter.helloworld;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

HashMap<String,String> cred = new HashMap<String,String>();
EditText u, p;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    cred.put("username", "password");

}


public void onClick(View v){
    this.u = findViewById(R.id.username);
    this.p = findViewById(R.id.password);
    login(this.u.getText().toString(), this.p.getText().toString());
}

public void login(String username, String password){
    if (cred.keySet().contains(username)){
        if (cred.get((String) username).equals(password)){
            Intent change = new Intent(this, picscreen.class);
            startActivity(change);
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}

}
```

(Inside the xml layout file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.peter.helloworld.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="85dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="233dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_toLeftOf="password" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Username"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="199dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@id/password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView3"
        android:text="Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The goal is to create a login screen.

The application crashes when the login is successful. I want to know why. If you need additional information, let me know.

Edit: LOGCAT (Sorry i'm new and didn't know an error log was needed for diagnosis, cheers!

```
11-25 11:24:51.033 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-25 11:24:51.404 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-25 11:24:51.785 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.peter.helloworld is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-25 11:24:51.804 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
11-25 11:24:52.750 3431-3446/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Debugger is active
11-25 11:24:52.822 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: Debugger has connected
11-25 11:24:52.822 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:53.025 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:53.227 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:53.428 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:53.630 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:53.838 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:54.040 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:54.242 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:54.449 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:54.650 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:54.851 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:55.053 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:55.255 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-25 11:24:55.456 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/System.out: debugger has settled (1458)
11-25 11:24:55.673 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-25 11:24:56.416 3431-3524/com.example.peter.helloworld D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
11-25 11:24:56.591 3431-3524/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
11-25 11:24:56.591 3431-3524/com.example.peter.helloworld I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-25 11:24:56.591 3431-3524/com.example.peter.helloworld D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-25 11:24:56.599 3431-3524/com.example.peter.helloworld D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa7341600: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
11-25 11:24:56.618 3431-3524/com.example.peter.helloworld D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7341600: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9ca1f70)
11-25 11:24:56.813 3431-3524/com.example.peter.helloworld D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7341600: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9ca1f70)
11-25 11:24:57.373 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld V/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring 0 children of 1073741833
11-25 11:24:57.392 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2912 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
11-25 11:25:00.021 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=28KB, data=30KB
11-25 11:25:00.022 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=28KB, data=30KB
11-25 11:25:00.022 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
11-25 11:25:00.650 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=58KB, data=58KB
11-25 11:25:00.650 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=58KB, data=58KB
11-25 11:25:00.650 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
11-25 11:25:02.967 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=99KB
11-25 11:25:03.029 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=116KB, data=71KB
11-25 11:25:03.505 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-25 11:25:03.505 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-25 11:25:05.305 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=123KB, data=98KB
11-25 11:25:05.307 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=98KB
11-25 11:25:05.307 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
11-25 11:25:12.140 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=248KB, data=169KB
11-25 11:25:12.140 3431-3444/com.example.peter.helloworld I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=245KB, data=145KB
11-25 11:25:20.114 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-25 11:25:20.131 3431-3431/com.example.peter.helloworld E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.peter.helloworld, PID: 3431
                                                                            android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.peter.helloworld/com.example.peter.helloworld.picscreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4488)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4446)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4807)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4775)
                                                                                at com.example.peter.helloworld.MainActivity.login(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                                at com.example.peter.helloworld.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: You should show the crash logs

Comment: insert logcat pls

Comment: paste your error here

Comment: Please edit your question and include your `Logcat` to make it more specific.

Comment: Can you please send logcat screenshot.

Comment: Either you have not declared picScreen activity in manifest or you have an uncaught exception in your picScreen activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your picscreen.java in AndroidManifest.xml

if it is not there then put it like below:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".picscreen" />

    </application>
```

Try this and let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I'm trying to learn so I'd rather not just copy paste a solution, why would this work and how do i expand on this idea to include multiple activities? What is exactly added in your solution and where would I put an abstract?

Comment: All the activities we create have to be mentioned in Androidmanifest.xml  otherwise your app will always crash...and manifest file will be mostly same except if you create service class, broadcastreciever class..you can replace the code in your manifest file I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared "picscreen" in manifest file. This is may be the root cause of the crash of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly but check your entry "picscreen" in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

have you declared picsscreen activity in your manifest file?